# Find volume of cube with the help of eqn of plane

Tags: 3d, volume, plane-curves

The volume of cube whose two faces lie on the plane 6x-3y+2z+1=0 and 6x-3y+2z+4=0?

Comment: hint: the planes are parallel - how far apart are these planes? do you need any more information?

Comment: You need to find the distance between the planes, and the volume of the cube will be that distance cubed.  Do you know how to find the distance between two planes?  Or the distance between a plane and a point not on the plane.  Or the distance between two lines, and think of how to expand that one more dimension?

Comment: Yes get it ,i know alll except how to expand one more dimensions .

Comment: Can you please make me understand what do you mean by it

Comment: You don't need to expand another dimension. You only need the distance between the 2 planes, the third dimension will be that same distance. Hence d x d x d = d^3

Comment: Thanx.. denimal, doug M,Adam

Answer (score 0):

Since we have parallel planes we can find the distance between the planes.

Let y = x = 0.

So 6(0) - 3(0) + 2z + 4 = 0 --> 2z = -4 --> z = -2.

Thus a point in that plane is (0,0,2). Now use formula to find distance between the other plane and this point. That is,

$D = \frac{|ax+by+cz+d|}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}}$

So $D = \frac{|6(0)+ -3(0)+2(-2)+1|}{\sqrt{6^{2}+(-3)^{2}+2^{2}}} = \frac{|-4 + 1 |}{\sqrt{36+9+4}} = \frac{3}{7}$.

Thus a cube with faces of these two planes would have a distance/length of $\frac{3}{7}$.

So $(\frac{3}{7})^{3} = \frac{27}{343}$

Comment: $z=-2$, so $\frac{3}{7}$ and $\frac{27}{343}$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.